# database update warning but no updates - google tag module issue?

Tags: 8, database

I'm on Drupal 8.8.2, and we've got a "database out of date" alert, requiring us to do database updates. When I attempt to do so at update.php, I get a message saying "no pending updates"

I re-ran cron to make sure the messages were up-to-date, and tried again. the message and issue remain.

When I look at logs I get three file permssions-type issues:

```
The file permissions could not be set on public://google_tag/primary/google_tag.data_layer.js.
The file permissions could not be set on public://google_tag/primary/google_tag.noscript.js.
The file permissions could not be set on public://google_tag/primary/google_tag.script.js.
```

Within the public folder, I checked the folder permissions. 
google_tag folder and it's subfolder, 'primary', are both 775 (drwxrwxr-x)
The three error-triggering files inside 'primary' are 664 (-rw-rw-r--)

Do these permissions need to change?
Is there another issue? Maybe something within the Google Tags module, itself?